# What orbital elements would show earth orbiting in the opposite direction?

Tags: orbital-motion

Would earth rotate in the opposite direction if inclination and argument of periapsis were 180 degrees?

Looking at this diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_periapsis

Thanks!

Comment: It never occurred to me before, but I don't think any of the orbital elements specify a revolution direction. I suppose you could set the period to negative to specify counterclockwise revolution, but I don't think changing any of the other elements would do it.

Comment: Thanks @barrycarter. Yes I noticed this when testing an orbit simulation program that does the following at high level:

Comment: a) New planets defined with a given mass, an initial position vector R0 and velocity vector V0; b) convert the initial vectors to orbital elements; c) calculate the new position vector as a functiton of time R(t). But I noticed during testing that inverting the velocity of a planet didn't change its direction..!

Comment: I thought the Earth has an orbital inclination of 0 degrees to the ecliptic (by definition) and therefore cannot have any inclination. This would make the argument of periapsis irrelevant since there is no ascending node.

Answer (score 0):

The proper definition of the inclination is the angle between the angular momentum vector and the pole (Z axis) of the reference frame. Defined this way i must be be between 0 and 180°. Other definitions (where i is the angle between two planes) are not rigorous.

When 0 ≤ i < 90° the orbit is called *prograde* or *direct*. For 90° < i ≤ 180° the orbit is called *retrograde*. When i = 90° the orbit is called *polar*.

So to reverse the direction of an orbit, you *subtract* 180° from the inclination.

You must also add 180° to the longitude of the ascending node. Note that the ascending and decending nodes swap places when the direction of revolution is reversed.

Finally, since the argument of periapsis is always measured from the ascending node. the new argument of periapsis is given by: 180° - ω (when ω ≤ 180°), or 540° - ω (when w > 180°).

Note that for polar orbits (i=90°), reversing the orbit direction does not change the inclination.